# Align Strings in columns in JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

I want to print Strings in JTextArea and align them properly. Its hard to explain so I will upload the screen shot of what I am trying to achieve.

[image: Screen shot of what I have got so far]

So Strings printed in each line are printed from Paper object which has parameters (id, title, author, date, rank). The data is read from a text file and is stored in a LinkedList using loadPaper() function.

Then displayPapers() function is used to display content of the Paper object to the JTextArea.
displayPapers() is listed below:

```
/** Print all Paper object present in the LinkedList paperList to textArea */
public void displayPapers(){
    // clear textArea before displaying new content
    displayTxtArea.setText("");

    Paper currentPaper;
    ListIterator<Paper> iter = paperList.listIterator();

    while(iter.hasNext()){
        currentPaper = iter.next();
        String line = currentPaper.toString();

        if("".equals(line)){
            continue;
        } // end if

        String[] words = line.split(",");
        displayTxtArea.append   ("  " 
                                + padString(words[0],30) 
                                + padString(words[1],30) 
                                + "    " 
                                + padString(words[2],30) 
                                + "  " 
                                + padString(words[3],30)  
                                + padString(words[4],30) 
                                + "\n");

        System.out.println(words);
        //displayTxtArea.append(currentPaper.toString());
    } // end while

    displayTxtArea.append("  Total " + noOfPapers + " entries!");

} // end showAllPaper
```

The padString() function adds spaces to the String so that all of them have same number of words. PadString() is listed below:

```
/** Add spaces to Strings so that all of the are of same number of characters
 *  @param str  String to be padded
 *  @param n    total number words String should be padded to
 * @return str  Padded string 
 */
private String padString(String str, int n){
    if(str.length() < n){
        for(int j = str.length(); j < n; j++){
            str += " ";
        } // end for
    } // end if
    return str;
} // end padString
```

I have worked on this for a while but still cant get the solution. As you can notice the above picture not everything is perfectly aligned as intended.

How do I align them perfectly so that it looks nicer? Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you use a JTable? It seems more appropriate to display data in columns.

Comment: I would rather go for a JTable that will give you the flexibility of playing around with column size and location etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Output will be aligned "properly" in your JTextArea only if you use a mono-spaced font. "Andale Mono 14" for example would do the trick.

Also, in order to make your life easier and avoid the padding hell, use [String.format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) with it's [syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax).

```
String format = "%1$5s %2$-40s %3$-20s";
String someLine;
while (whatEver...) {
   ... 
   someLine = String.format(format, aNum, aName, aDate);
   jTextArea1.append(someLine + "\n");
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Thats what I was preciously looking for. Solves my problem. Cheers.

Comment: JTable may be fine, but sticking to JTextArea allows adding additional unformatted information to the same component as well as more tables if needed.

Comment: mono-spaced does it perfectly.

Answer (score 8):

Use a [`JTable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html) instead (for what is apparently tabular information).  See [How To Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more details & working examples.

[image: Table Sort Demo]

Answer (score 6):

You may use [HTML](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/html.html) with swing component or use [JEditorPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html).

```
JLabel jt=new JLabel();
jt.setText("<html>
            <table border='1'>
               <tr><th>No</th><th>Name</th></tr>
               <tr><td>1</td><td>Mr.A</td></tr></table></html>");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also change the font of the JTextArea if it is allowed in your problem

```
textArea.setFont(new Font("monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 12));
```