# Java Formatter receipt printing issue

Tags: java, formatter, point-of-sale, receipt

I am designing a receipt to print out in Java using the PrinterJob class.

I need some advice.

Based on the example I saw here.

http://www.javadocexamples.com/java_source/__/re/Receipt.java.html

How do I store the output given in the example above in a jTextPanel?
I will then print out the text content inside the jTextPanel using the PrinterJob class.

I want to get the following output when I print out the text content inside the jTextPanel from my POS printer.

[image]

Below are the codes I have so far.

```
String s = String.format("Item Qty Price", "%-15s %5s %10s\n");
        String s1 = String.format("---- --- -----","%-15s %5s %10s\n");
        String output = s + s1;

        jTextPane1.setText(output);

        PrinterJob printerJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
        PageFormat pageFormat = printerJob.defaultPage();
        Paper paper = new Paper();
        paper.setSize(180.0, (double) (paper.getHeight() + lines * 10.0));
        paper.setImageableArea(margin, margin, paper.getWidth() - margin * 2, paper.getHeight() - margin * 2);
        pageFormat.setPaper(paper);
        pageFormat.setOrientation(PageFormat.PORTRAIT);
        printerJob.setPrintable(jTextPane1.getPrintable(null, null), pageFormat);
        printerJob.print();
```

Any advice on how can I proceed?

Comment: Check out this [Stackoverflow post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8533612/align-strings-in-columns-in-jtextarea). The answer you seek is there.

Comment: Thanks! Checking it out

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The order in which you pass arguments to `String.format` is wrong. The format string goes first (the one with the percentage signs), and then you pass multiple arguments, one argument for each percent in the format string.

So in your case:

```
String s = String.format("%-15s %5s %10s\n", "Item", "Qty", "Price");
String s1 = String.format("%-15s %5s %10s\n", "----", "---", "-----");
```

You also need a format string for the line items.
From your output, that could be:

```
"%-15s %5d %10.2f\n"
```

(Which you would use as:

```
String line = String.format("%-15s %5d %10.2f\n", itemName, quantity, price);
```

)

If you want to truncate your itemName if it's longer than 15 characters, you can use:

```
// "%.15s %5d %10.2f\n"
String line = String.format("%.15s %5d %10.2f\n", itemName, quantity, price);
```

Comment: How to handle cases where the item name is very long?

Comment: I added the solution for that to the answer.

Comment: how do i wrap long itemName to multiple lines?

Comment: @Smith You'll need to then spit up the itemName yourself in a for-loop; every line except for the last only has a 15-character itemName portion, and the last one has the quantity and the price too. But if you want to line-wrap nicely you'll need to do it at word boundaries, except if the word is already longer than 15 characters.