# Unable to customize String format to print column-wise features

Tags: java

I am trying to print the result of my computation into `JTextArea` in columns similar to table. I have three features (three columns) and I use the following `String format` solution that I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8533612/align-strings-in-columns-in-jtextarea) but it does not align them properly. Since I don't understand `"%1$5s %2$-40s %3$-20s";`, kindly can someone fix it?

```
String format = "%1$5s %2$-40s %3$-20s";
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    String s = String.format(format, i*5, km.runningTime[i], km.DB[i]);
    jtextarea.append(s+ "\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the explanations in the **Format String Synta**x paragraph of the `Formatter` [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) of Oracle.

For example:  `%1$5s` means: first argument (it starts to count at `1` and not `0`), 5 is the width and s means `string`. In `%2$-40s`, the minus sign means that the result will be left-justified. I let you guess the last part.

I hope it helps.